# Implementation of A Star (A*) Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

Disclaimer: I have little background in Java, since I am predominantly a C# developer.

Would like to have the java implementation of A* algorithm.
Yes, I saw many versions of the same online and I am unable to choose between them.

I am looking for an A* algorithm implementation that uses all new features of java that makes the algorithm faster(even if a tad bit). The reason is that we are implementing that for path-finding on an [`MMO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_game) and so, performance is the top priority.

Any pointers ( on atleast where to look ) ?

Comment: Can you give us links to versions you already found? And, by the way, using "new features of Java" won't make an algorithm faster.

Comment: Link expired again, here's the newest for anyone like me who finds this:
https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/AStar.java

Comment: @BattleBarnes the included bidirectional A* is even faster

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try several, measure, pick the fastest, adapt to your needs. Performance is mostly determined by the choice of heuristic function, which is independent of A* proper.

If the heuristic is fixed, the implementation of the priority queue is likely to become the bottleneck, so try [pairing heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap). These are some of the fastest heap data structures in practice, and they have the advantage over binary heaps that they allow for O(1) insertion time + amortized O(log n) pop-min. This is important in the expected case of many A* loops, where the queue is filled, but never entirely emptied, i.e., the number of insertions is much greater than the number of pops.

If memory becomes an issue, switch to iterative-deepening A* (IDA*) or recursive best-first search (RBFS).

If nothing works, consider using an approximation algorithm (greedy search). Simply optimizing a decently written A* loop isn't going to give you tremendous speed-ups.

See [Russell and Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) for algorithms and a good discussion of the issues.

Comment: what Datastructure should be used for the `closedList`?

Comment: A hash table. Or a red-black tree. Or a splay tree. Or whatever turns out to be fastest. @st0le, you're right that this matters, but in my experience, fast sets are easier to come by than fast priority queues.

Comment: @sk0le: if a closed set is needed at all, that is.

Comment: @Robert, thanks. "How to implement A*" comes up on SO every now and then, and "read R&N" is almost always the answer ;)

Answer (score 10):

If performance is your top priority, A* is probably not your best choice.  A* provides an exact solution, and as a result will keep processing away until it finds the correct answer.  There are other lightweight solutions that give good enough solutions in much faster time: e.g enforced hill climbing or best-first, even a simple depth first.

Comment: +1. Optimizing A* code won't win the OP a performance trophy.

Comment: -0, as yes, A* is probably not that efficient but the alternatives you need are speed-up techniques specific to path-finding like contraction hierarchies and similar.

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, A* does not *always* provide the optimal answer. It only does if the heurstics is [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality).